# how do I get stroke (border) around multiple rectangles with d3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

The code below does almost exactly what I want, but for some reason it doesn't display a border around my rects.

```
d3.select("frac")
        .append("div")
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(this.fracData)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
.style("width", 80 / this.fracData.length + "vw")
        .style("background-color", (d) => {
          if (d == 0) {
            return "white";
          } else if (d == 1) {
            return "blue";
          } else if (d == 2) {
            return "red";
          } else if (d == 3) {
            return "yellow";
          }
        });
```

I'm trying to get it to work like my jsfiddle seen here https://jsfiddle.net/sbrevolution5/gpueyrtf/61/

Answer (score 2):

Your `div` elements aren't SVG elements. They're regular old HTML elements.

In your linked snippet you use the following css:

```
border: 2px solid black;
```

In your question you are essentially applying the following css:

```
stroke: black;
stroke-width: 2px;
```

This wouldn't be valid for an HTML element. You'll need to apply valid CSS for an HTML element. So instead of:

```
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
```

Use:

```
    .style("border", "2px solid black")
```